# Google-Earth-Engine + Jupyter : filterBounds not working in Landsat imageCollection

Tags: remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, landsat-8, jupyter-notebook

I have a simple problem of not being able to select a single Landsat image using filterBounds within Jupyter environment. It used to work just fine in Earth Engine's online interface. I don't know why it should fail now.

```python
import ee
ee.Initialize()

lat = 45
lon = -100
Radius = 1000

roi = ee.Geometry.Point([lat, lon]).buffer(Radius)
point = ee.Geometry.Point (lat, lon)
start = ee.Date('2017-01-01')
finish = ee.Date('2018-12-01')
L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1")

Time_Set = ee.ImageCollection(
  L8.filterDate(start, finish)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 2))
)
print('Number of images in Time Set: ', Time_Set.size().getInfo())

Space_Set = ee.ImageCollection(
    L8.filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(lat, lon))
)

print('Number of images in Space Set: ', Space_Set.size().getInfo())
```

Printed results:

```
Number of images in Time Set:  64343
Number of images in Space Set:  0
```

Comment: Please include relevant code inside code tags within this question. Screenshots of code make it hard to reproduce the problem for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [ee.Geometry.Point()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eegeometrypoint) constructor, the dimension ordering of the `coord` parameter is `longitude,latitude` (or `x,y`), rather than `latitude,longitude`. Once you reverse your parameters, you should see some resulting images in the filtered collection.

```
Space_Set = ee.ImageCollection(
    L8.filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat))
)
print('Number of images in Space Set: ', Space_Set.size().getInfo())
```

results in:

```
Number of images in Space Set:  295
```

Comment: Thanks, Tyler. This works. I suspected this might be the case so I tried some lat = lon points for trial such as (0,0) and (2,2) but that yielded 0 images as well. Now I wonder why might that have happened.